# How to know if my phone has NFC technology?

Tags: nfc

I bought the Samsung Galaxy Note phone in Greece, but the store in which I bought the phone brought it directly from Samsung in France (that's what they told me), and the language that the phone had when I first booted the device was in German (so I suppose this phone was purposed for Germany).

Is there any way to find out whether my phone has NFC technology or not?

Comment: [Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir) probes the hardware. If it doesn't show then you probably doesn't have NFC. Also, `com.android.nfc` is the default Android app which takes care of NFC. You should be having it unless your OEM deliberately removed it and introduced some other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

For some years now, there are many free apps that will give you this information.  I have one called `Phone Tester` which shows this screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a declaration of support for NFC capability an OEM would most likely add **android.hardware.nfc** to device's feature list - Which can be queried via adb:

***adb shell pm list features | grep android.hardware.nfc***

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#nfc-hw-features)